# Importance of study of mathematics in algorithm design and other computer science fields

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for a discussion state that, why  study of mathematics  in designing algorithms, and find out efficient solution for algorithmic problems is so important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [my answer here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136063/121717).

Basically, the different areas of math are used in different areas of computer science as well.

Specifically for algorithms, for example, knowing probability theory can help with defining and designing probability-based algorithms - which have a potential to be more efficient than regular old deterministic ones.